# Query post filtering not working due to apostrophe in custom field

Tags: php, html, wordpress, filtering

I have an issue with my post filtering. I am working on a property website where I want the user to be able to search by location. But the problem is that some of the locations have apostrophes(Bishop's Stortford) in and this causes the page to load nothing.

edit:

My posts are set up with Custom post types and Advanced Custom Fields. Town, county and postcode are acf text fields on the posts which hold the address values.

How can I solve this? can I make town and county accept apostrophes? heres my code;

```
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="get">
<label>Min:</label>
<input type="number" name="min_price" id="min_price">

<label>Max:</label>
<input type="number" name="max_price" id="max_price">


<label>Bedrooms:</label><br>
<select name="min_beds">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6+">Six+</option>
</select>

<select name="max_beds">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6+">Six+</option>
</select>

<label>Location</label><br>
<input type="text" name="location">

<input type="submit">
```

```
<?php 
if($_GET['min_price'] && !empty($_GET['min_price'])){
    $min_price = $_GET['min_price'];
}else{
    $min_price = 0;
}

if($_GET['max_price'] && !empty($_GET['max_price'])){
    $max_price = $_GET['max_price'];
}else{
    $max_price = 10000000;
}

if($_GET['min_beds'] && !empty($_GET['min_beds'])){
    $min_beds = $_GET['min_beds'];
}else{
    $min_beds = '1'; 
}

if($_GET['max_beds'] && !empty($_GET['max_beds'])){
    $max_beds = $_GET['max_beds'];
}else{
    $max_beds = '6+'; 
}

if($_GET['location'] && !empty($_GET['location'])){
    $location = $_GET['location'];
}

$posts = get_posts(array(
'posts_per_page'    =>  -1,
'post_type'         =>  'property',
'orderby'           =>  'date',
'meta_query'        =>  array(
    'relation'  => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'       => 'property_status',
        'value'     => 'For Sale'
    ),

    array(
        'key'       => 'property_price',
        'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
        'value'     => array($min_price, $max_price),
        'compare'   => 'BETWEEN'
    ),

    array(
        'key'       => 'bedrooms',
        'value'     => array($min_beds, $max_beds),
        'compare'   => 'BETWEEN'
    ),

    array(
        'relation'  => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'       => 'town',
            'value'     => $location,
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        ),

        array(
            'key'       => 'county',
            'value'     => $location,
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        ),

        array(
            'key'       => 'postcode',
            'value'     => $location,
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
)
));
?>
```

Comment: This feels like an accidental SQL injection. How is the data retrieved?

Comment: Add the block of code where you are querying from database.

Comment: I have updated my question to explain how my post filtering works

Comment: I have added all the code

Comment: Add code for ```get_posts``` method implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $request)`
I'm guessing this should work. Please try and leave a feedback so I update answer If necessary.

```
if($_GET['location'] && !empty($_GET['location'])){
   $location = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['location']);
}
```

Comment: Where should I use this?

Comment: Thanks mate. It works perfectly. What does that line of code do?

Comment: I have no idea what that means haha. I'm quite new to php. I'll look it up thanks